# Mvx ShowViewModel not triggering init

Tags: mvvmcross

On a slide out drawer I have a link which performs a ShowViewModel passing in parameters.  I use the MvxBundle to set flags to clear the back stack.  If the view is already shown and I click on the slide out drawer and click the link again which executes the ShowViewModel, the Init is not subsequently called.  Further, the way our screen is designed the user would have to hit the back button to leave the screen.  Is it not possible to invoke Init via ShowViewModel if that view is already shown?

Answer (score 0):

`Init` is a certain step of ViewModel lifecycle.
You cannot trigger it outside after your ViewModel is create though you can call it manually if you have a reference to it.

make sure your init looks like that:

```
public void Init(//any number of parameters you passed at ShowViewModel)
{
}
```